# adb devices is not recognised as a known command

Tags: android, adb

I am trying to set-up a command in Android studio that would allow me to see the current active devices like in this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WuGkXg4PjKU) (1:39:41):
[image: Tutorial screenshot]

I have opened the environment settings and created the variable *adb devices* like it was explained in the tutorial
 [image]

However, when I run it in Android Studio Terminal, the command is not recognised:
[image]

What did I do wrong?

Comment: can you find the the adb application in the directory? If not install them https://www.xda-developers.com/install-adb-windows-macos-linux/

Comment: restart terminal and check?

Comment: @Julian It does exist.

Comment: @Ragu I did that

Comment: It may be due to some admin permissions. Can you check the command in cmd with admin permission. Sometimes system restart also helps

Comment: It may be blocked from your anti Virus, can you add it to whitelist or trun it off and try again.

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan It gives the same result. But, I have tried another commmand 'mongod' and it works. Although both of them have been defined in the same place, and in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your naming. Try remove the white space and it will work.
Cause you type adb with argument devices.
Try change your variable to `adb`

then type

```
$ adb devices
```

and it will work